# How can I serve from apache several projects and disallow that users project from reading other's project?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, debian, permissions

Let's explain that mess, I have some projects in one server under debian 6, each one located at their respective /home/USER with it's respective user. I want the users that login as "project1" not being able to read files under other project folders  (/home/project2 ie.). But I want apache to serve each project without permission forbidden.

I can get one thing or the other but not both at the same time. If I block users from reading the others with "chmod 0750 /home/project*" i get a "Forbidden" from apache.

How this could be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to change the permissions of your projects to `750` and set the owner to `user1:www-data`. This way the owner user has full privileges on the folder. The group `www-data` has read+exec permissions which should be enough to serve contents from that folder.

Comment: It works! I thought that being the user folder the same group as the other it was the user's group also but it isn't. One user does not belong to the same group of its home folder. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use [extended ACLs](http://idolinux.blogspot.com.au/2008/12/linux-acls.html) to grant the user running Apache access, or do the usual and just give `o+x,g-rwx` and put everyone in the same group.